# Gravity Forms Pre Submission Check

Tags: jquery, plugin-gravity-forms

I have only one field with an email address. If the field is empty, i don't want the form to be submitted at all, but just focus on the field. I have tried many variations but no matter what i do, the form is still submitted. I am also using AJAX for the shortcode.

```
jQuery(document).on('gform_pre_render_32', function() {
    jQuery(document).bind('gform_page_loaded', function() {
        jQuery('#gform_32').on('submit', function(event) {
            var email = jQuery('#input_32_6').val();
            if (email === '') {
                jQuery('#input_32_6').focus();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```